# Reset angular form with $setPristine

Tags: forms, angularjs

Using $scope.form.$setPristine() returns undefined.

```
<html>
    <form name="my_form">
        ...
    </form></html>
```

Defining the controller on my $routeProvider

```
.when('page_name', {
    templateUrl: '...',
    controller: function($scope) {
        console.log(my_form); // returns the form object
        my_form.$setPristine(); returns Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method '$setPristine'
        console.log($scope.my_form); // returns undefined
        $scope.my_form.$setPristine(); // returns Cannot call method '$setPristine' of undefined
    }
}
```

I've also tried passing the form to the $scope via jQuery `$scope.my_form = $('form');` which, as expected, just sent the form object and resulted in the first error. What does it take to get this method to work?

I tried putting a Plunker together to demonstrate but I can't seem to get routing to work on there properly.

Everything else about the form works btw. I would just like to know how to get $setPristine to work.

Comment: using Angular 1.2.0-rc.2

Comment: where is your `ng-view`?

Comment: @Cherniv on the page. The html is obviously truncated. Or rather, on the parent page. The form is on a template page that is passed to ng-view.

Answer (score -2):

Put the form and the ng-controller at the same level...

```
<form name="my_form" ng-controller="my_controller">
```

That's working for me.

(sorry about my english) ;-)