# $setPristine() not working for form reset with angular 1.4

Tags: angularjs

HTML :

```
<form name="ContactForm" novalidate >
    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="contact.firstName" name="uFirstName" required="" autocomplete="off"/>
      </label>
        <br>
        <div ng-show="ContactForm.$submitted || ContactForm.uFirstName.$touched" ng-hide="hidespan">
        <span class="error" ng-show="ContactForm.uFirstName.$error.required">Tell us your First Name.</span>
        <span class="error" ng-show="ContactForm.uFirstName.$error.text">This is not a valid First Name.</span>
        </div> 
        </div>
    <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="ContactForm.$valid && contactReq(contact)">
      Submit
    </button> 
    </form>
```

JS

```
var defaultForm = {
        firstName : "",
        lastName : "",
        email : "",
        message : ""
    }

    $scope.contact = angular.copy(defaultForm);

    $scope.contactReq = function(contact){
        $scope.ContactForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.contact = angular.copy(defaultForm);
        console.log('empty');
    }
```

I am using AngularJS v1.4.3  for phonegap development. I want to reset the form after clicking the submit button. But when i am doing set Pristine i am getting the following error: **"ERROR: Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.ContactForm.$setPristine')"**
I tried many links related same but nothing is working for me.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: links that i tried 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015010/angularjs-form-reset-error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865125/angularjs-form-reset
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191744/setpristine-not-working
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431335/reset-angular-form-with-setpristine
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029889/angular-setpristine-not-working

Comment: i think ContactForm is not defined in the controller scope

Comment: @AlainIb 1st place, why should he define `ContactForm` in controller?

Comment: Post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem. My guess is that your form is inside a `ng-if`, or another directive which has its own scope.

Comment: for reference http://jsfiddle.net/charms/AhGDC/24/

Comment: @pankaj because he try to make `$scope.ContactForm.$setPristine();`

Comment: @AlainIb sir do look at the the form API, how it works with angular, angular does create form name `object` internally, with all its validation properties for each form field

Comment: Try: `this.ContactForm.$setPristine();` If it works you have a scope issue, just like @JB Nizet wrote.

Comment: Here is example plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/mCH8e2xLMrSlVzWsVDID?p=preview

Comment: I tried "this.ContactForm.$setPristine();" but got Error: this.ContactForm.$setPristine is not a function. (In 'this.ContactForm.$setPristine()', 'this.ContactForm.$setPristine' is undefined)

Comment: using $scope getting "Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.ContactForm.$setPristine')"

Comment: Hello @VishalSingh Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Hello @Jose ..Yes, I have fixed this issue...by adding $scope.untouched = false; $scope.ContactForm.$setUntouched();.....Also I am refreshing my page after submit.

Answer (score 0):

ContactForm should be on the scope.
Just a guess: Copy the values of the default form to the model before you call setPristine()

Answer (score 0):

I had a strange issue using Safari 9.01.  My form inputs were not editable after I switched from my Login to Registration page.

So I tried using the $setPristine() method and experienced the same problem.  I found that putting a timeout in the reset function allowed me to access the form.

You could try:

```
    $scope.contactReq = function(contact){
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.ContactForm.$setPristine();
            $scope.contact = angular.copy(defaultForm);
            console.log('empty');
        },10);
    }
```

If that doesn't work try using `this.ContactForm.$setPristine();` instead of `$scope.ContactForm.$setPristine();`

My problem ultimately ended up being a issue with the way I was using ui-router to change between my views.

Good luck!